# Using Tooltipster with ClipboardJS, problem loading tooltips on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, tooltipster

I have in my project Bootstrap5, ClipboardJS, JQuery and Tooltipster.

I have tried to follow exactly the initial instructions on the [Tooltipster website](https://www.heteroclito.fr/modules/tooltipster/#getting-started), I could not figure out what I missed, here are two captions, the first of the JavaScript scripts and the other of one the components (buttons) where a tooltip should appear after clicking one of them:

```html
<!-- (Right before </body>) -->

<!-- ClipboardJS -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(btns);
</script>

<!-- Tooltipster -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn').tooltipster({
            trigger: 'click'
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded ms-2" title="Copied!  " type="button" data-clipboard-target="#email">
                        Copy
                    </button>
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: The Tooltipster documentation pretty clearly identifies jQuery as a dependency, but you're loading jQuery _after_ you load Tooltipster. That might not be your only problem, but I'm pretty sure it is one. You should be using the browser's web development console to get more information. I'm sure there are errors in there that you're not reporting in your question. Your question would be better asked if you provided the specific error messages you're seeing rather than a generalized "it doesn't work" type statement.

Comment: That was actually the only problem, it worked like a charm! thank you, @Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to load JQuery before Tooltipster as Marc said in a comment, I was not aware it matters.